# How to use Api key in Web Api for service authentication using forms authentication

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using MVC 4 Web Api and I want the users to be authenticated, before using my service.

I have implemented an authorization message handler, that works just fine.

```
public class AuthorizationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly AuthenticationService _authenticationService = new AuthenticationService();

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> apiKeyHeaderValues = null;
        if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("X-ApiKey", out apiKeyHeaderValues))
        {
            var apiKeyHeaderValue = apiKeyHeaderValues.First();

            // ... your authentication logic here ...
            var user = _authenticationService.GetUserByKey(new Guid(apiKeyHeaderValue));

            if (user != null)
            {

                var userId = user.Id;

                var userIdClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.SerialNumber, userId.ToString());
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { userIdClaim }, "ApiKey");
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            }
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I use forms authentication.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(UserModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = _authenticationService.Login(model);
            if (user != null)
            {
                // Add the api key to the HttpResponse???
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

When I call my api:

```
 [Authorize]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public string GetLists()
    {
        return "Weee";
    }
}
```

The handler can not find the X-ApiKey header.

Is there a way to add the user's api key to the http response header and to keep the key there, as long as the user is logged in?
Is there another way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following article http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-cookies
Using it I configured my AuthorizationHandler to use cookies:

```
public class AuthorizationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService = new AuthenticationService();

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var cookie = request.Headers.GetCookies(Constants.ApiKey).FirstOrDefault();
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            var apiKey = cookie[Constants.ApiKey].Value;
            try
            {
                var guidKey = Guid.Parse(apiKey);

                var user = _authenticationService.GetUserByKey(guidKey);
                if (user != null)
                {

                    var userIdClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, apiKey);
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { userIdClaim }, "ApiKey");
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
            }
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I configured my Login action result:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = _authenticationService.Login(model);
            if (user != null)
            {
                _cookieHelper.SetCookie(user);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect username or password");
            return View(model);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Inside it I am using the CookieHelper, that I created. It consists of an interface:

```
public interface ICookieHelper
{
    void SetCookie(User user);

    void RemoveCookie();

    Guid GetUserId();
}
```

And a class that implements the interface:

```
public class CookieHelper : ICookieHelper
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase _httpContext;

    public CookieHelper(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    public void SetCookie(User user)
    {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(Constants.ApiKey, user.UserId.ToString())
        {
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1)
        };

        _httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }

    public void RemoveCookie()
    {
        var cookie = _httpContext.Response.Cookies[Constants.ApiKey];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);
            _httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
    }

    public Guid GetUserId()
    {
        var cookie = _httpContext.Request.Cookies[Constants.ApiKey];
        if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
        {
            return Guid.Parse(cookie.Value);
        }

        return Guid.Empty;
    }
}
```

By having this configuration, now I can use the Authorize attribute for my ApiControllers:

```
[Authorize]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

This means, that if the user is not logged in. He can not access my api and recieves a 401 error. Also I can retrieve the api key, which I use as a user ID, anywhere in my code, which makes it very clean and readable.

I do not think that using cookies is the best solution, as some user may have disabled them in their browser, but at the moment I have not found a better way to do the authorization.

Answer (score 1):

From your code samples it doesn't seem like you're using Web Forms. Might you be using Forms Authentication? Are you using the Membership Provider inside your service to validate user credentials?

You can use the HttpClient class and maybe its property DefaultRequestHeaders or an HttpRequestMessage from the code that will be calling the API to set the headers.

Here there are some examples of HttpClient:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Thanks! You are right I meant Forms Authentication. I edited my question. I am not using a Membership Provider, instead I have created a custom authentication logic.
I can not use the HttpRequestMessage, because I am doing my authentication using MVC Controller and returning an Action Result (or I do not know of a way to use it).